# SharePoint 2013 Access App. Calculate ageing of Status

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I am using SharePoint(2013 on prem) Access App and new to Access app.

It has Task table which has different Status like- Draft, Inprogress, ReadyforReview, Closed etc.The status keeps on changing on one state to another for eg. Inprogress to ReadyforReview, ReadyforReview to Draft, and Draft to Inprogress etc.

I want to calculate the time that item was in each status. For eg. 3 hours in Draft, 6 hours in Progress etc.

I created another table that will store the Item ID, Status, Start Date, End Date, Total(Calculated- Difference End Date and Start Date). I can populate the Start date, however I am not able to populate the end date. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.